# How to define drop location in Visual studio online using vNext

Tags: azure-devops

I came across this site while looking for the answer but it is related to XAML 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394.aspx

Currently my drop is empty.

[snapshot of the vso using vNext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqkYh.png)

Comment: You forgot to erase your login name on the screen shot :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are using vNext build while you are referring to the XAML build article.

You can create a XAML build definition in Team Explorer, then you'll see the "Copy build output to server" in the XAML build definition UI.

If you want to use vNext build  definition to specify the drop location, you can add a task called: Publish Build Artifacts to manage artifacts of the drop.

Comment: I  have "Publish Build Artifacts". It has fields  "Copy Root" = $\xxxx , "Contents" = **\bin, "Artifact Name"= drop, "Artifact Type" = Server , Control Options, "Enabled" = Checked , "Always run" = Checked .

Comment: On Console I can see build progressing.  Test cases run and I am getting code coverage.

Comment: Open your build, then you'll see the tab Artifacts, the drop will be there.

Comment: What is the name of the field that defines drop location. Above(refer to my  nov5 notes ) I have listed all fields of the tab. Which one is defining drop directory?

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/build/publish-build-artifacts